# How can I forecast a y-variable based on multiple x-variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm testing code like this.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tabulate import tabulate
#Seaborn for easier visualization
import seaborn as sns

# Load Iris Flower Dataset
# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_to_file\\train.csv')
df.shape
list(df)


# the model can only handle numeric values so filter out the rest
# data = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).interpolate().dropna()

df1 = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
df1.shape
list(df1)
df1.dtypes


df1 = df1.fillna(0)

#Prerequisites
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


#Split train/test sets
# y = df1.SalePrice
X = df1.drop(['index'], axis=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=.33)


# Train model
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=2, n_estimators=1000)
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


# Feature Importance
headers = ['name', 'score']
values = sorted(zip(X_train.columns, model.feature_importances_), key=lambda x: x[1] * -1)
print(tabulate(values, headers, tablefmt='plain'))


(pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
   .nlargest(10)
   .plot(kind='barh'))
```

[image]

This works fine on some sample data that I found online. Now, rather than predicting a sales price as my `y` variable. I'm trying to figure out how to just get the model to make some kind of prediction like `target = True` or `Target = False` or maybe my approach is wrong.

It's a bit confusing for me, because of this line:  `df1 = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])`. So, only numbers are included, which makes sense for a `RandomForestRegressor classifier`.  I'm just looking for some guidance on how to deal with a non-numeric prediction here.

Comment: Sounds like you want to predict. Sklearn has a built in `.predict()` method you can use given features for the instances you want to predict. You just have to pass the `X` data you want to predict for.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a classification problem here with 2 classes (True, False). To get started take a look at a simple logistic regression model.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

Since you are using sklearn try:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html